# Find minimum steps required to reach n

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve a Dynamic programming problem which is as follows but unable to solve it.

*You are given a primitive calculator that can perform the following three operations with the current number : multiply  by 2, multiply  by 3, or add 1 to . Your goal is given a positive integer , find the minimum number of operations needed to obtain the number  starting from the number 1*

**I found the solution on stackoverflow itself** but unable to understand what's going on.

I have heard that every DP problem can be solved by creating matrix which I was trying to do but don't know where I am going wrong. The table is created below which shows number of steps required to reach to **n** from 1, initially I take values as infinity.

```
i / j           0           1             2            3                4              5
plus 1          0           1             2            3                4              5
multiple by 2   0           infinity      2            infinity         3             infinity
multiple by 3   0           infinity      infinity     2                infinity      infinity
```

I am trying to solve this problem in Python.
Can someone please help me.

I found the solution which is as follows but not able to understand exactly what is going on:

```
import math
target = int(input())

def optVal(target, cache):
    result = [1] * cache[-1]  # 1
    for i in range(1, cache[-1]): # 2
        result[-i] = target  # 3
        if cache[target-1] == cache[target] - 1:  # 4
            target -= 1
        elif target % 2 == 0 and (cache[target // 2] == cache[target] - 1):  # 5
            target //= 2
        else:  # 6 # target % 3 == 0 and (cache[target // 3] == cache[target] - 1):
            target //= 3
    return result

cache = [0] + [math.inf] * target  # 1
for i in range(1, len(cache)):  # 2
    temp1 = math.inf
    temp2 = math.inf
    temp3 = math.inf

    temp1 = cache[i - 1] + 1
    if i % 2 == 0:
        temp2 = cache[i // 2] + 1
    if i % 3 == 0:
        temp3 = cache[i // 3] + 1

    cache[i] = min(temp1, temp2, temp3)

print('Minimum operation: ', cache[target] - 1)
finalLst = optVal(target, cache)
print(' '.join([str(x) for x in finalLst]))

Input: 
5
Output:
3
1245
```

Comment: the problem statement is similar to Edit distance. checkout https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/edit-distance-dp-5/

Comment: I hope it can help you: https://skerritt.blog/dynamic-programming/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This algorithm is split in two parts. The first is in the main, the second is in the `optVal` function.

The first part builds the `cache` list, where `cache[i]` holds the minimum number of steps necessary to arrive from `0` to `i` applying, at each step, one of the three possible operations: `+1`, `*2` or `*3`. This list is the 1-dimensional case of the matrix you read about.

When `cache[i]` is calculated, all indices lower than `i` already have been calculated. One can get to `i` in three possible ways, so a maximum of three possible sources of `i`, i.e., elements of `cache`, need to be examined: `i-1`, `i//2` and `i//3`, but `i//2` only if `i` is even, and `i//3` only if `i` can be divided by 3. These elements of `cache` are compared, and the content of the winner, incremented by 1 (because of the extra step to get to `i`), is stored in `cache`. This process is bootstrapped by putting a `0` in `cache[0]`. In the end, `cache[target]` will contain the minimum number of steps to get to `target` starting from `0` (which is 1 more than the steps to get there starting from `1`, which is how the problem was stated – note that you only can apply the `+1` operation to move out from `0`).

Now, if I had written the code, I probably would have stored the “parent” or the “winning operation” of each `cache[i]` together with the number of steps to get there (BTW, those `math.inf` are not really needed, because there always is a finite number of steps to reach `i`, because of the `+1` operation.) The approach of the author is to infer this information from the content of the possible parents (max 3) of each `cache[i]` that needs to be examined. In both cases, the chain of “ancestors” has to be reconstructed backwards, starting from `cache[target]`, and this is what happens in `optVal()`.

In `optVal()` the `target` is changed at each iteration (a bit confusingly), because at each iteration the info you have is the minimum number of steps needed to reach a certain target number. Knowing that, you look at the 1, 2 or 3 possible parents to check which one contains exactly that number of steps minus 1. The one that passes the test is the actual parent, and so you can continue building the chain backwards replacing `target` with the parent.

Comment: Great explanation, I was able to understand it finally. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

to solve this DP, you have to construct a table of minimum number of steps required to get n, if one two or all the operations were available. you will be creating it left to right, top to bottom, ie 1 to n, add 1 to mul 3. As you go down more number of operations are available

A cells value only depends on the value above it (if available) and atmax 3 values in the left side eg. for (n = 6),(mul 3) cell will depend only on `(n = 6),(mul 2)` and `(n = 2)(mul 3)`, `(n = 3)(mul 3)`, `(n = 5)(mul 3)`. you will then compare these values and whichever is smaller after operation, you will put that value, so you will be comparing value of `(n = 2)(mul 3) + 1` vs `(n = 3)(mul 3) + 1` vs `(n = 5)(mul 3) + 1` vs `(n = 6)(mul 2)`, and then whichever is smaller you will put that value

since n = 1 is given, the first column would have all the values as zero

for n = 2, its values will depend on values of n = 1. you can "add 1" or "multiply by 2" (1 step), both are valid. so this column will have all the values as 0 + 1 = 1

for n = 3, its values will depend on values of n = 1 (because 1 = 1/3 of 3) AND n = 2. if you can only "add 1" or "multiply by 2", then you will choose to add 1 to n = 2 so total steps 1+1 = 2. BUT if you could also multiply by three you will need only one step so 0 + 1 = 1. since 1 < 2 you will put 1 as this value. so the entries for n = 3 is 2, 2, 1

for n = 4, it will depend on n = 3 (add 1), and n = 2 (mul 2). so the values will be 3, 2, 2

for n = 5, it will depend on n = 4 (add 1). so the values will be 4, 3, 3

so the minimum steps are 3 to reach n = 5

final table:

```
    1  2  3  4  5
add 1  0  1  2  3  4
mul 2  0  1  2  2  3
mul 3  0  1  1  2  3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
int rec(vector<int> &dp,int n)
{
    if(n==1) return 0;
    if(dp[n]!=INT_MAX) return dp[n];
    return dp[n]=min({1+rec(dp,n-1),(n%2==0)?1+rec(dp,n/2):INT_MAX,(n%3==0)?1+rec(dp,n/3):INT_MAX});
}
string genseq(vector<int> &dp, int n){
    string res="";
    while(n>1)
    {
        res=to_string(n)+" "+res;
        if(dp[n-1]==(dp[n]-1)) n--;
        else if(n%2==0&&( dp[n/2]==dp[n]-1)) n/=2;
        else if(n%3==0&&( dp[n/3]==dp[n]-1)) n/=3;
    }
    return "1 "+res;
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> dp(n+1,INT_MAX);
    dp[0]=0;
    dp[1]=0;
    std::cout << rec(dp,n) << std::endl;
    std::cout << genseq(dp,n) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You misunderstood the question: The op didn't ask for _another solution_ but for an _explanation_ of the one he showed. Also: The question has a Python tag, not C++. You should remove your answer.